# Android Location Services slow on tablet

Tags: android, android-activity, geolocation

I have the following code that takes around 1.5 minutes to find a location on two tablets that I've tested on, and it also takes around 30 seconds to load on a phone without GSM/CDMA enabled. Does anyone have any ideas why this takes so long to run without cell service? I have declared the class containing this code to be a LocationListener.

Here is my code:

This is in my OnCreate method:

```
    locationNotificationBus = new EventBus();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
    locationCriteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( locationCriteria, false );
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0,this);
```

This is declared inside of the class itself:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.wtf( "LOCATOR: ", "Location Has Changed." );
    Log.d("New Location", "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude());
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    locationNotificationBus.post(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("LOCATOR: ", "Status Has Changed.");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("LOCATOR: ", "Provider enabled.");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("LOCATOR: ", "Provider disabled.");
}
```

It is my understanding that Coarse location can also use Wi-Fi to determine location. Is this not the case? If not, how do I go about using Wi-Fi?

Comment: because without network connection it has to wait for a GPS signal since that is now the only way to get a location and that can take some time to get

Comment: because GPS must download the almanac from the gps satellites before it can even begin to try to calculate location. Without any external data, you have to wait for the almanac to be transmitted. That's why there's A-GPS - grabbing the various almanac updates from faster "local" services, meaning you don't have to wait for the satellites to send it out.